# Outlook 2016: Add exchange account using script / automatic ( OSX > 10.12 )

Tags: macos, ms-office, exchange-activesync

Is there a way to add Exchange Account to Outlook using scripts / automatically ?
My scenario is:

Fresh install of Volume Licence Office 2016.

Opened Outlook

On opening Outlook, it should get configured to account automatically from a config file or account should be system login credentials ?

Answer (score 1):

After using **applescript** and **procedure** mentioned here, I added Outlook account successfully using script.
https://github.com/talkingmoose/Outlook-Exchange-Setup-5